# Remove objects with duplicate properties from List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List of objects in C#.  All of the objects contain the properties dept and course.
There are several objects that have the same dept and course.

How can I trim the List(or make a new List) where there is only one object per unique (dept & course) properties.

[Any additional duplicates are dropped out of the List]

I know how to do this with a single property:

```
fooList.GroupBy(x => x.dept).Select(x => x.First());
```

However, I am wondering how to do this for multiple properties (2 or more)?

Comment: Does your list need to be sortable?

Comment: I have already sorted the list by the time I reach this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use multiple properties you can use an anonymous type:

```
var query = fooList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Dept, x.Course })
                   .Select(x => x.First());
```

Of course, this depends on what types `Dept` and `Course` are to determine equality. Alternately, your classes can implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and then you could use the [`Enumerable.Distinct` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) that accepts a comparer.

Comment: Both Dept and Course are ints.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick!  However, I am wondering since I am using an anonymous type how can I pass around "var query"?
What sort of method signature would accept that?  Or is there some kind of conversion I do to return back to its original type, etc.,?

Comment: @Baxter the query above returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is your original class used in `fooList`. The anonymous type was used only for the grouping; the final projection made by the select statement is the original class. For this query you would pass it around to anything that accepted an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you need a list, add `.ToList()` to the end of the query.

Comment: So I could do something as simple as:

List<OriginalType> myGroupedList = query.ToList();

Comment: This helped me a lot, I originally used a foreach to compare, and a list with 250k objects took 75 seconds to run. With this solution it now takes 0.12 seconds with the same list.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use the LINQ `Distinct` extension method together with an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>`. It requires you to implement a comparer; however, the latter is reusable and testable.

```
public class FooDeptCourseEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return
            x.Dept == y.Dept &&
            x.Course.ToLower() == y.Course.ToLower();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        unchecked {
            return 527 + obj.Dept.GetHashCode() * 31 + obj.Course.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    #region Singleton Pattern

    public static readonly FooDeptCourseEqualityComparer Instance =
        new FooDeptCourseEqualityComparer();

    private FooDeptCourseEqualityComparer() { }

    #endregion
}
```

My example uses the singleton pattern. Since the class does not have any state information, we do not need to create a new instance each time we use it.

My code does not handle `null` values. Of course you would have to handle them, if they can occur.

The unique values are returned like this

```
var result = fooList.Distinct(FooDeptCourseEqualityComparer.Instance);
```

---

UPDATE

I suggest using a generic EqualityComparer class that accepts lambda expressions in the constructor and can be reused in multiple situations

```
public class LambdaEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, bool> _areEqual;
    private Func<T, int> _getHashCode;

    public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> areEqual,
                                  Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        _areEqual = areEqual;
        _getHashCode = getHashCode;
    }

    public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> areEqual)
        : this(areEqual, obj => obj.GetHashCode())
    {
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer<T> Members

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _areEqual(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _getHashCode(obj);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can use it like this

```
var comparer = new LambdaEqualityComparer<Foo>(
    (x, y) => x.Dept == y.Dept && x.Course == y.Course,
    obj => {
        unchecked {
            return 527 + obj.Dept.GetHashCode() * 31 + obj.Course.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
);

var result = fooList.Distinct(comparer);
```

Note: You have to provide a calculation of the hash code, since `Distinct` uses an internal `Set<T>` class, which in turn uses hash codes.

---

UPDATE #2

An even more generic equality comparer implements the comparison automatically and accepts a list of property accessors; however, you have no control, on how the comparison is performed.

```
public class AutoEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, object>[] _propertyAccessors;

    public AutoEqualityComparer(params Func<T, object>[] propertyAccessors)
    {
        _propertyAccessors = propertyAccessors;
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer<T> Members

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        foreach (var getProp in _propertyAccessors) {
            if (!getProp(x).Equals(getProp(y))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        unchecked {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (var getProp in _propertyAccessors) {
                hash = hash * 31 + getProp(obj).GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage

```
var comparer = new AutoEqualityComparer<Foo>(foo => foo.Dept,
                                             foo => foo.Course);
var result = fooList.Distinct(comparer);
```